# creating plots index out of bounds error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the function code and sample data below, that is throwing the error below.  The code is used to create plots to evaluate training time, accuracy, and fscore for three different types of models.  I'm trying to modify the vs_evaluate function so it only shows plots for training time and accuracy but I'm getting the index out of bounds error below.  I've commented out a couple of parts of the funtion, changed subplot from 2,3 to 2,2 and removed the fscore related entries from enumerate.  Can anyone see what's causing the issue and suggest how to fix it?

Data:

```
print(results)

{'LinearSVC': {0: {'train_time': 0.0013530254364013672, 'acc_train': 0.69999999999999996, 'pred_time': 0.0007898807525634766, 'acc_test': 0.73076923076923073}, 1: {'train_time': 0.001964092254638672, 'acc_train': 0.90000000000000002, 'pred_time': 0.0012090206146240234, 'acc_test': 0.65384615384615385}, 2: {'train_time': 0.005677938461303711, 'acc_train': 0.69999999999999996, 'pred_time': 0.000701904296875, 'acc_test': 0.66153846153846152}}, 'LogisticRegression': {0: {'train_time': 0.0014522075653076172, 'acc_train': 0.69999999999999996, 'pred_time': 0.0009410381317138672, 'acc_test': 0.73076923076923073}, 1: {'train_time': 0.0015349388122558594, 'acc_train': 0.80000000000000004, 'pred_time': 0.0006539821624755859, 'acc_test': 0.69230769230769229}, 2: {'train_time': 0.0023081302642822266, 'acc_train': 0.69999999999999996, 'pred_time': 0.0006170272827148438, 'acc_test': 0.68461538461538463}}, 'AdaBoostClassifier': {0: {'train_time': 0.005421876907348633, 'acc_train': 0.59999999999999998, 'pred_time': 0.0018930435180664062, 'acc_test': 0.69230769230769229}, 1: {'train_time': 0.17421698570251465, 'acc_train': 0.90000000000000002, 'pred_time': 0.014720916748046875, 'acc_test': 0.61538461538461542}, 2: {'train_time': 0.14342188835144043, 'acc_train': 0.59999999999999998, 'pred_time': 0.012198925018310547, 'acc_test': 0.67692307692307696}}}
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-76d9833e28b9> in <module>()
     25 
     26 # Run metrics visualization for the three supervised learning models chosen
---> 27 vs_evaluate(results, accuracy) #, fscore)

<ipython-input-112-11d513962c2a> in vs_evaluate(results, accuracy)
     45 
     46                 # Creative plot code
---> 47                 ax[j/3, j%3].bar(i+k*bar_width, results[learner][i][metric], width = bar_width, color = colors[k])
     48                 ax[j/3, j%3].set_xticks([0.45, 1.45, 2.45])
     49                 ax[j/3, j%3].set_xticklabels(["1%", "10%", "100%"])

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

Calling function:

```
vs_evaluate(results, accuracy)
```

Code:

```
# Function for evaluating model performance

###########################################
# Suppress matplotlib user warnings
# Necessary for newer version of matplotlib
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category = UserWarning, module = "matplotlib")
#
# Display inline matplotlib plots with IPython
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
###########################################

import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def vs_evaluate(results, accuracy):
    """
    Visualization code to display results of various learners.

    inputs:
      - learners: a list of supervised learners
      - stats: a list of dictionaries of the statistic results from 'train_predict()'
      - accuracy: The score for the naive predictor
      - f1: The score for the naive predictor
    """

    # Create figure
    fig, ax = pl.subplots(2, 2, figsize = (11,7))

    # Constants
    bar_width = 0.3
    colors = ['#A00000','#00A0A0','#00A000']

    # Super loop to plot four panels of data
    for k, learner in enumerate(results.keys()):
        for j, metric in enumerate(['train_time', 'acc_train', 'pred_time', 'acc_test']):
            for i in np.arange(3):

                # Creative plot code
                ax[j/3, j%3].bar(i+k*bar_width, results[learner][i][metric], width = bar_width, color = colors[k])
                ax[j/3, j%3].set_xticks([0.45, 1.45, 2.45])
                ax[j/3, j%3].set_xticklabels(["1%", "10%", "100%"])
                ax[j/3, j%3].set_xlabel("Training Set Size")
                ax[j/3, j%3].set_xlim((-0.1, 3.0))

    # Add unique y-labels
    ax[0, 0].set_ylabel("Time (in seconds)")
    ax[0, 1].set_ylabel("Accuracy Score")
    #ax[0, 2].set_ylabel("F-score")
    ax[1, 0].set_ylabel("Time (in seconds)")
    ax[1, 1].set_ylabel("Accuracy Score")
    #ax[1, 2].set_ylabel("F-score")

    # Add titles
    ax[0, 0].set_title("Model Training")
    ax[0, 1].set_title("Accuracy Score on Training Subset")
    #ax[0, 2].set_title("F-score on Training Subset")
    ax[1, 0].set_title("Model Predicting")
    ax[1, 1].set_title("Accuracy Score on Testing Set")
    #ax[1, 2].set_title("F-score on Testing Set")

    # Add horizontal lines for naive predictors
    ax[0, 1].axhline(y = accuracy, xmin = -0.1, xmax = 3.0, linewidth = 1, color = 'k', linestyle = 'dashed')
    ax[1, 1].axhline(y = accuracy, xmin = -0.1, xmax = 3.0, linewidth = 1, color = 'k', linestyle = 'dashed')
    #ax[0, 2].axhline(y = f1, xmin = -0.1, xmax = 3.0, linewidth = 1, color = 'k', linestyle = 'dashed')
    #ax[1, 2].axhline(y = f1, xmin = -0.1, xmax = 3.0, linewidth = 1, color = 'k', linestyle = 'dashed')

    # Set y-limits for score panels
    ax[0, 1].set_ylim((0, 1))
    #ax[0, 2].set_ylim((0, 1))
    ax[1, 1].set_ylim((0, 1))
    #ax[1, 2].set_ylim((0, 1))

    # Create patches for the legend
    patches = []
    for i, learner in enumerate(results.keys()):
        patches.append(mpatches.Patch(color = colors[i], label = learner))
    pl.legend(handles = patches, bbox_to_anchor = (-.80, 2.53), \
               loc = 'upper center', borderaxespad = 0., ncol = 3, fontsize = 'x-large')

    # Aesthetics
    pl.suptitle("Performance Metrics for Three Supervised Learning Models", fontsize = 16, y = 1.10)
    pl.tight_layout()
    pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

in the # Creative Plot Code  changing 3 to 2 solved the error.  For example ax[j/2, j%2]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error:
You have 2 by 2 subplots. As j loops from 0 to 3, you get the following indexes,

```
ax[j/3,j%3] =

ax[0,0] #j = 0
ax[0,1] #j = 1
ax[0,2] #j = 2  #Problem is here
ax[1,0] #j = 3
```

Instead you can do something like this:

```
ax[0 if j in [0,1] else 1,0 if j in [0,2] else 1] =

ax[0,0] #j = 0
ax[0,1] #j = 1
ax[1,0] #j = 2
ax[1,1] #j = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this.  Does replacing 3 with 2 in the creative plot code as I suggest below, also solve the issue?  I'm not getting the error anymore, I just want to make sure it's still doing what I think it should be doing.

Comment: That also solves the problem and gets you the indexes you need.